# update panel / postback / javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, updatepanel, postback

I'm hoping someone can help me out with an update panel / postback / javascript issue.

I have a div box that is moved up the screen via a click and some javascript (btnOpenWindow).
Within that div I have a button which causes a postback which is all good, but this results in the window zipping back to its original position defined in css, and not in its current position as affected by the javascript.

I can see what's going on, but not sure how to tackle it.

So the question is - how do I get the postback to occur without the div moving?

The state of the window, either 0 or 1 is defined in hdnPopupWindowState. Can I somehow use this to check the position of the div and then save and re-render it after the postback? What's the best way?

Thanks in advance...

```
    function btnOpenWindow() {

        var showWindow = document.getElementById('<%= hdnPopupWindowState.ClientID %>');

        if (showWindow.value === "0") {
            showWindow.value = "1";
            $('#popupWindow').animate({ bottom: '+=310px' });
        }
        else {
            showWindow.value = "0";
            $('#popupWindow').animate({ bottom: '-=310px' });
        }
    }



    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="popupWindow" class="popupWindow">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPopupWindowState" Value="0" runat="server" />
                <asp:Table ID="tblTest" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow47" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableCell >Welcome</asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
                <input type="button" CausesValidation="false" id="btnStartChat" runat="server"  onserverclick="btnStartChat_Click" value="FFS" class="btnStartChat" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through some clunky server side script registering I've done some fiddling and come up with the following fix:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var showChat = document.getElementById('<%= hdnChatWindowState.ClientID %>');

        if (showChat.value === "1") {
            //$('#chatWindow').animate({ bottom: '+=310px' });
            $('#chatWindow').css({ bottom: '+=310px' });
        }
    })

}
```